# Pass angular loop variable to jquery function and update as each time angular variable changes

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have an image slider in angular in which images are sliding and its working perfectly fine, now what i want is that each active image should be sent to jquery function whenever a person hover over the image for image zoom, i am using cloud-zoom image plugin. so when i pass a static image link, the plugin works fine, but in angular js case, the image does't pass because jquery runs before angular so all it gets is {{photo.image}} and not original value inside this variable.

html code for slider:

```
  <div class="col-md-4 my">
      <div class="row slider cust">
           <img ng-repeat="photo in imageData" id="zoom1" class="slide" ng-swipe-right="showPrev()" ng-mouseover="hoverIn()" ng-mouseleave="hoverOut()" ng-swipe-left="showNext()" ng-show="isActive($index)" src="{{photo.image}}" />
              <span class="arrow prev" href="#" ng-click="showPrev()"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
              <span class="arrow next" href="#" ng-click="showNext()"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      </div>
      <div class="row" style="margin-top: -15px;">
           <ul class="nav">
               <li ng-repeat="photo in imageData" ng-class="{'active':isActive($index)}">
                  <img src="{{photo.image}}" ng-click="showPhoto($index);" />
               </li>
           </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Controller code:

```
 $scope._Index = 0;
            $scope.isActive = function (index) {
                return $scope._Index === index;
            };
            var timer = null;
            $scope.hoverIn = function () {
                $interval.cancel(timer);
                timer = null;
            };
            $scope.hoverOut = function () {
                if (timer === null) {
                    timer = $interval(function () {
                        call();
                    }.bind(this), 4000);
                }
            };
            timer = $interval(function () {
                call();
            }.bind(this), 4000);
            $scope.showPrev = function () {
                $scope._Index = ($scope._Index > 0) ? --$scope._Index : $scope.imageCount - 1;
            };
            function call() {
                if ($scope.imageCount > 0) {
                    $scope._Index = ($scope._Index < $scope.imageCount - 1) ? ++$scope._Index : 0;
                }
            }
            $scope.showNext = function () {
                $scope._Index = ($scope._Index < $scope.imageCount - 1) ? ++$scope._Index : 0;
            };
            $scope.showPhoto = function (index) {
                $scope._Index = index;
            };
```

Jquery code:

```
   <script>
                    $(function () {
                        $.fn.resize = function (a) {
                            var d = Math.ceil;
                            if (a == null) a = 200;
                            var e = a,
                                f = a;
                            $(this).each(function () {
                                var b = $(this).height(),
                                    c = $(this).width();
                                if (b > c) f = d(c / b * a);
                                else e = d(b / c * a);
                                $(this).css({
                                    height: e,
                                    width: f
                                })
                            })
                        };
                        $("#zoom1").resize(200);
                        $('#zoom1').each(function () {
                            var call = $(this);
                            var src = call.attr('src');
                            var str = '<a href="' + src + '" class="cloud-zoom" rel="adjustX: 0, adjustY:0" />';
                            call.wrap(str);
                            $(".cloud-zoom, .cloud-zoom-gallery").CloudZoom();
                        });
                    });
                </script>
```

in this jquery code when i wrote the src variable in console, it gets {{photo.image}}.

Comment: How are you determining when Angular is done processing and when jQuery should look for the src value?

Comment: its because when i write the src variable in console it prints {{photo.image}} instead of actual src image, because value is there when i see it using inspect element.